# Why isn't my slideshow working?

Tags: html, css

So for a website I'm building I wanted to put a photo slideshow on the home page. However, for some reason all the pictures that I wanted to use are not in one slideshow but they are instead spread out on the page into indivdual images. I think there is a problem with my html but I'm not sure.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("../background1.jpg");
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: deeppink;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: pink;
}


/*Slideshow container*/

.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}


/*Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position right next button */

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


/*Number text*/

.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}


/*The indicators*/

.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
}


/*Fading animation*/

.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to Fazbear Entertainment</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fnaf.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fnaf.js"></script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFB6C1">
<div class="header">
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Prices</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
        <img src="fnafworld.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Welcome to Fazbear Entertainment</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
        <img src="funtimefreddy.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Funtime Freddy</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
        <img src="funtimefoxy.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Funtime Foxy</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
        <img src="baby.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Baby</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
        <img src="Ballora.png" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Ballora</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onClick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
</br>
</body>

</html>
```

Is it because of the way I formatted it?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: could you uplaod to jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link

Comment: You're not giving the minimum amount of code needed to solve your question. I can't see `currentSlide()` and `plusSlides()` declarations.

Comment: you didn't need to close the <link> tag it's singular

Comment: Need to at least see the CSS for `mySlides` and `fade` ...

Comment: what you meant by </br> ?

Comment: I added the css code. Sorry about that!!

Comment: You need to tell us which Jquery plugin you are using. Also it looks like you have not even included the plugin files, Include the plugin files and initialise the plugin by following the plugin documentation